# StructureMap and Proto.Actor in .NET Core 2

Tags: structuremap, proto.actor

I have been using [Proto.Actor](http://proto.actor/) and specifically the `ActorFactory` to spawn actors. To be able to use these features I need to add `services.AddProtoActor()` to the `ConfigureServices` method of my startup class.

However, now I want to transition to using StructureMap as my IoC container, but the two do not appear to play nicely together - when I add the following code from guides I have found online:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureIoC(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // static class method that scans assemblies
    IContainer container = IocContainer.SetupContainer(); 
    container.Configure(config =>
    {
        config.Populate(services);
    });


    return container.GetInstance<IServiceProvider>();
}
```

When it tries to run `config.Populate` I get the following error:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the
>   range of valid values. Parameter name: EventStream must have at
>   least one public constructor to be plugged in by StructureMap

Does anyone have any ideas how to get the IActorFactory created correctly as a singleton in StructureMap (or have a workaround)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, using StructureMap removes the need I had for the `ActorFactory` itself. So instead of getting the actor's PID from the factory I have two lines:

```
var props = Actor.FromProducer(() => container.GetInstance<MyActorType>());
var pid = Actor.Spawn(props);
```